# Randomly select from a dictionary for proxy use

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, dictionary, proxy

With the following data how can I randomly select one of the dictionary items and pull both the xtest and the yblob?

`{"xtest": "yblob", "xtest1": "yblob1", "xtest2": "yblob2", "xtest3": "yblob3", "xtest4": "yblob4", "None": "None"}`

I'm wanting to use it in conjunction with some proxies so ideally I need something like:

`.ProxyHandler({"http":"{x}:{y}"})`

This would automatically be inputting based on the random selection chosen from the dict at the top however if it finds the dictionary item `"None": "None"` then it would not use a proxy so in effect I need two variables:

```
x = xdict
y = ydict
```

Anyone got any pointers or ideas, it would be much appreciated.

Kind regards, AEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet should accomplish what you're looking for:

```
import random
d = {"xtest": "yblob", "xtest1": "yblob1", "xtest2": "yblob2", "xtest3": "yblob3", "xtest4": "yblob4", "None": "None"}

#choose a random x
x = random.choice(d.keys())
if x == "None":
    proxy = None
else:
   y = d[x]
   proxy = {"http": "%s:%s" % (x, y)}
```

Answer (score 2):

So here, I'm using randint to select one of the elements from the original dictionary of items - named dd

```
>>> import random
>>> dd = {"xtest": "yblob", "xtest1": "yblob1", "xtest2": "yblob2", "xtest3": "yblob3", "xtest4": "yblob4", "None": "None"}
>>> k = dd.keys()[random.randint(0, len(dd))]
>>> v = dd[k]
>>> k, v
('xtest3', 'yblob3')
```